# unique value based on another column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Issue is I need to have a unique value in a column based on value from another column.

for ex : I have item_ID and product column

For every item_ID there should only be unique values in the product column.

```
item_ID    Product
1               1
1               2
1               4
2               1
```

but if I insert 1 in item_ID and 1 in product now, it should throw an error.
I have no idea how to implement this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Something like `SELECT DISTINCT(prod_id), item_id WHERE prod_id != item_id`?

Comment: @scrowler Wilmer has given the solution to my problem below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a unique index for both columns

```
alter table yourtable add unique index(item_ID, Product);
```